# Validating a domain without subdomain, requires a TLD, no IPs, and so on?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I need to validate my user's inputs through my C# .NET service. The users can input a domain, which I need to take care of. However, there are some rules to this:

- No subdomains, so only domains are allowed
- It cannot be an IP address
- It cannot be just a hostname (so `localhost` is a no-go)
- It cannot contain illegal characters (like `[\½(` and so on)
- The TLD does not necessarily need to be valid, so `test.mmmmmmm` should pass)

So far I've tried a bunch of things, but none of them seem to fulfil my needs. I simply need to verify, if a domain is valid. Here's a bunch of things I've tried:

```
if(!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(DomainName, UriKind.Absolute))
//problem: has to be an uri, but http://1 would pass

if (Uri.CheckHostName(DomainName) == UriHostNameType.Unknown)
//problem: abc would pass (probably also IPs)

if (Uri.CheckHostName(DomainName) != UriHostNameType.Dns)
//problem: abc would pass (probably also IPs)

Regex: (\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9])
//problem: IPs and subdomains are allowed but neither abc or invalid characters are allowed
```

Seems like something easy to do. I'm not sure if combining some of these might work, but I highly doubt it. This discussion has been brought up plenty of times, but none of them suits my needs.

Any clue what to do?

Comment: Since the rules for what constitutes a domain have changed several times (e.g. all have 3 names except for `org`/`com`/`net`/`gov`; no wait, now we have new TLDs expected to issue 2 name domain names), perhaps you should approach the problem from how you will *use* this info. E.g. if you need them routing email, do MX lookups on it instead? Just as one example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I could do a lookup on the domain, but if it's not registered yet, that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got a pretty good solution, that I think works out great: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zjg3Ep

```
private bool IsDomainValid(string DomainName)
{
    //no hostnames
    if (DomainName.Split('.').Length <= 1) return false;

    //cannot start or end with a dot - simply invalid
    if (DomainName[0] == '.' || DomainName[DomainName.Length - 1] == '.') return false;

    //cannot start or end with a hyphen - simply invalid
    if (DomainName[0] == '-' || DomainName[DomainName.Length - 1] == '-') return false;

    //hostname cannot start or end with a hyphen - simply invalid
    if (DomainName.Split('.')[0] == "-" || DomainName.Split('.')[0][DomainName.Split('.')[0].Length - 1] == '-') return false;

    //cannot have two dots right after eachother
    if (DomainName.Matches($"[\\.]{2}")) return false;

    //cannot be an IP
    if (Uri.CheckHostName(DomainName) == UriHostNameType.IPv4) return false;

    //cannot contain illegal characters
    if (!DomainName.Matches($"^[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+$")) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Checks out a lot of the things I wanted, so I'm generally pretty happy.